# Play framework tests with beforeeach

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I'm trying to setup and tear down a database in Play Framework 2.1 test suite using Scalatest

we actually had setup with

```
 running(FakeApplication()){

 }
```

but I would like to setup the database before each individual test, from my understanding of Scalatest you can do this with

```
override def beforeEach(){

}
```

So I tried to run a couple of Squeryl queries from within and got some errors about the Session being closed.

So I then tried to create a session within the beforeEach method:

```
override def beforeEach(){
   import org.squeryl.SessionFactory

   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance()
   // classOf[org.postgresql.Driver]
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver)
   val props = new Properties()
   props.setProperty("user","db")
   props.setProperty("password","db")
   SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(()=>
     Session.create(
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/db", props),
    new PostgreSqlAdapter))

   CloudUsers.truncateUsers()
   Servers.truncateServers()
}
```

This has cleared out the session errors but I now get:

```
Could not run test Controllers.UserTest: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Throwable escaped the test run of 'Controllers.UserTest':     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

So in a nutshell, can I run a beforeEach setup method in Play or do I just have to munge it with some bootstrap at the top of each test?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2):

Had a sleep on it then tried putting

```
running(FakeApplication()) {
}
```

within the

```
override def beforeEach(){

}
```

code, which seems to do the trick, not sure of the implications this has, if any, on the Play Framework, but does the job for now.

Comment: I did the same and also didn't have any problems with that. Let us know if you find any :)

Answer (score 0):

beforeEach method from [BeforeAndAfterEach](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.9.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach) trait can be used only in ScalaTest tests, but not in the application itself.

> it can be mixed into **suites** that need methods invoked **before and after running each test**.

So yes, this fixture was created to make some settings before each test will be run by the suite. You can read about this and some other ScalaTest fixtures [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#composingFixtures)

Comment: Thanks Alexlv, I know how it works, but as its run in conjunction with play framework, i also need a running (fake) application for the tests to converse with during the test phase.